# UK standard visit visa refusal due to inadequate financial

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-funds

My application for a standard visit visa to the United Kingdom has been refused stating that the documents I have provided do not demostrate what my finacial circumstances are and how I support myself on a daily basis. As a non working student I am financially supported by my family and in most of the cases I use my sister’s bank account (who is also a non working student in Vienna). Due to the fact that we live together, we found it more convenient to use her account for common expenses, such as rent, electricity, and food expenses etc., as well as some of my personal expenses like insurance and telefone bills. Therefore my question would be if in addition to my bank balance of the last 6 months (which is used rarely) I also provide the bank balance of my sister would it be an accurate reflection of my finacial circumstances? Otherwise how could she state that she has taken this responsibility? Moreover which supporting documents would be appropriate for me to add to the application in order to prove my intention of leaving the United Kingdom at the end of my visit and that I am able to maintain and accomodate myself there? Would it also be an advantage to include my parents’ bank statements as well?
In addition to this I am planning of visiting my boyfriend there, and I would be grateful if you could provide me with some information regarding the invitation letter, such as what it should consist of and whether it is necessary or not?